# How to commit update to ports?

Tags: freebsd

5.5.32 version of MariaDB (MySQL replacement) was released in 18th july but in FreeBSD ports we still have 5.5.31.
What ways I have to commit this update to ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a patch ready to update the port to 5.5.32, create a PR and email the maintainer of the port. If you don't have a patch ready, email the maintainer of the port and ask *politely* of an update if it's very urgent for you.